# Get content URI of images stored on sdcard using File Provider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I have an Image File stored in sd card with an Absolute path as - `storage/4469-0C17/DCIM/...` and another image stored in internal storage with an absolute path - `/storage/emulated/0/`

I am using FileProvider to share it with external apps.

Now, I am able to share images stored in internal-storage but for the image stored in external storage, it throws an error as -
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/4469-0C17/DCIM/....`

My Manifest -

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application>
    .....
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Code -

```
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("image/*");
 File imageFileToShare = new File(filePath);
 Uri imageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFileToShare);
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
 share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: in your provider_paths.xml file instead of '.' try '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and another image stored in internal storage with an absolute path

That is what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> but for the image stored in external storage, it throws an error as -
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/4469-0C17/DCIM/....

First, that is [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), not external storage.

Second, `FileProvider` does not support removable storage.

Comment: So on android N my app will crash anyways. ? Is there a way to support it.?

Comment: @Harshit: AFAIK, your app does not have direct filesystem access to `storage/4469-0C17/DCIM/`, so I am not sure where you got that path from.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FileProvider which as you have seen yourself is very limited you better derive your own provider from ContentProvider.

Then you can serve any file you want.

CommonsWare has a nice example how to set up such a file provider.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your provider_paths.xml this:

```
<root-path path="." name="external_files" />
```